# What is the ID parameter for custom post types in query_posts?

Tags: custom-post-types, query-posts

In the Admin section I'm using quesry posts to get the title and content of a custom post

this query_posts('post_type=sfnewsletter'); will get me the content I need but unfortunately what I need to do now is to pass the ID of the custom post via a form and then retrieve that content

I've tried

```
query_posts('p=32');  
query_posts('page_id=32');  
query_posts('page=32');  
query_posts('sfnewsletter_id=32');
```

And not only do I not get the right custom post some of them return a post with an ID of 14 (not the first or last post)

I have confirmed that 32 is the correct ID for the custom post I am trying to get.

THIS IS THE FORM

It passes the ID correctly

```
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo sfn_form_url(); ?>" >

            <table class="form-table">

                <tr valign="top"><th scope="row"><?php _e( 'To', 'sfnewsletter' ); ?></th>
                    <td>
                        <select name="sfnewsletter_to" id="sfnewsletter_to">
                        <option value="0">Please Choose</option>
                        <?php wp_dropdown_roles() ?>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr valign="top"><th scope="row"><?php _e( 'Newsletter', 'sfnewsletter' ); ?></th>
                    <td>
                        <select name="sfnewsletter_newsletter" id="sfnewsletter_newsletter">
                        <option value="0">Please Choose</option>
<?php 
                        query_posts('post_type=sfnewsletter'); 
                        if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();

                            echo '<option value="' .get_the_ID(). '">' .get_the_title(). '</option>';

                        endwhile; endif;

?>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>

            <p class="submit">
                <input id="sfnewsletter_hidden" class="regular-text" type="hidden" name="sfnewsletter_hidden" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'SEND' ); ?>" />
                <input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php _e( 'Send Message', 'sfnewsletter' ); ?>" />
            </p>
        </form>
```

THIS IS THE SOLUTION I CAME UP WITH. THE ANSWER I HAVE ACCEPTED THE RIGHT WAY TO DO IT THOUGH, MY WAY IS A FUDGE

---

ok, I have come up with a work around that suits my situation.

Since I don't seem to be able to use my custom post ID in the query I have used the ID from the form and converted it into the permalink and then used that in the query like so

```
    $sfnewsletter_slug = basename( get_permalink($sfnewsletter_newsletter) );

    $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' =>'sfnewsletter', 'posts_per_page'=>1, 'name'=>$sfnewsletter_slug ) );
```

This gives me the output I am looking for.

---

Comment: You should post an example of your form.

Comment: ok, added the code for the form

Comment: ok, I have answered my own question but can't post the answer for about 6 hours. I'm using the permalink to get the results I need. I'll be back in 7 hours to post my query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
query_posts('post_type=sfnewsletter&p=32');
```

Comment: ok, that worked, thank you. Better than my answer too

Answer (score 0):

The example queries you've posted are for *Pages*, not custom post types. "p" is for "post" post type, "page_id" and "page" are for "page" post types.

Your query should be:

```
query_posts(array('post_type' => 'sfnewsletter'));
```

That will grab he newsletter posts.  If you want a specific ID, then within that query, you just need to ask for

```
query_posts(array('post_type' => 'sfnewsletter'));
if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); 
$postid = $post->ID; // retrieves the post IDs within the Loop.
```

Comment: Hi Shelly, I have tried p and page_id to no avail. 

As I said I've found a solution that allows me to get the one custom post I need rather than looping through all of the custom posts until I get to the right ID (which seems very inefficient IMHO).

Unfortunately I can't post my answer for another 5 hours because of Stack Exchange restrictions

Comment: Yes, but what I was saying was "p" and "page" (in the query) are for *standard* post types.  In your above examples, you were trying to pull ID's from *custom* post types. That's why it wasn't working - that's all I was pointing out with that. I do so want to see your solution though! :)

Comment: ah, I see, sorry I misread your comment. TBH I'm surprised we can't just use ID to get what ever we want, I'm sure there's a good reason though

Comment: I've updated my original question with the solution I had cobbled together, Milo's solution is the correct way though, at least IMHO